# How to count the number of operations in a algorithm has square root

Tags: algorithm, time, count, big-o, analysis

I have a problem with counting operations. Here is my algorithm:

```
  m = 0  //1 operations
  while(n>= 2)
  n = sqrt(n)
  m++
  return m++ // 1 operations
```

I don't know how to count the rest operations. I'm just new to algorithm analysis. Please help me thank you.

Comment: Hint: find which `n` makes exactly 1 iteration of the loop, then find which `n` makes exactly 2 iterations, 3 iterations, ... Repeat a couple of times, find the pattern, then come up with an inductive proof.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.